# Lista dentro de otra Lista JSON

Tags: json, lista

Buenas a todos gracias por su apoyo de antemano: tengo este Json

```
        "items": [
        {
            "sku": "YR-001",
            "quantity": 10,
            "description": "Descripcion del Producto",
            "price": 2000,
            "discount_rate": 10,
            "taxes": [
                {
                    "tax_category": "IVA",
                    "tax_rate": 19
                }
            ],
            "retentions": [
                {
                    "tax_category": "RET_FUENTE",
                    "tax_rate": 1
                }
            ]
```

estoy tratando de "embeber" las listas: taxes y retention dentro de la lista items. Uso datatable para recoger la información, de esta manera:

```
            Dim DTL As DataTable = CapaDatos.Metodosfacturas.ItemsJsonDI(TxtTipo.Text, TxtCodigo.Text)
        If DTL IsNot Nothing AndAlso DTL.Rows.Count Then
            Dim DR1 As DataRow = DTL.Rows(0)
            Dim TASA As String = DR1("TASIMP")
            listaTaxes.Add(New Tax("IVA", TASA))
            For Each DR2 As DataRow In DTL.Rows
                    listaItems.Add(New Item(DR2("SKU"), DR2("quantity"), DR2("description"), DR2("price"), DR2("discount_rate"), listaTaxes, ListaRetenciones))
            Next
        End If
```

El tema que me sucede es que solo me toma el IVA del primer item no necesariamente el que le corresponde al item es decir si el primer item tiene tax_rate de 19 todos los demas items que tenga el documento toman ese mismo valor. Agradezco su ayuda.Pongo aqui el metedo del dataTable.

```
    Public Shared Function ItemsJsonDI(Tipo As String, Codigo As Integer) As DataTable
    Try
        Using CN As New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.Conexion)
            Dim SQL As String = String.Format("SELECT TIPLFA,CODLFA,POSLFA,ARTLFA AS sku,Round(CANLFA,2) AS quantity,DESLFA AS Description,PRELFA as price,DT1LFA AS discount_rate, F_IVA.TASIMP FROM F_LFA INNER JOIN F_IVA ON F_LFA.IVALFA = F_IVA.CODGRU
            WHERE TIPLFA=""{0}"" AND CODLFA={1} ORDER BY POSLFA;", Tipo, Codigo)
            Using DA As New OleDbDataAdapter(SQL, CN)
                Using DT As New DataTable
                    DA.Fill(DT)
                    Return DT
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Err.ItemsJsonDI No.: " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Err.")
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

---

Mil Gracias por responder, Si, efectivamente el Json es el que debo lograr, ese es al que le apunto (Solo que para el ejemplo esa factura solo tiene un item, pero en la realizdad pueden y son casi siempre mas de 2 items, cada uno con su tax y retencion) Cada item tiene un tipo de impuesto, lo que requiero es que se recorra la tabla detalle de Facturas (F_LFA) y se vaya agregando a la lista ITEMS, ademas que agregue a la lista Taxes el impuesto correspondiente de cada item que se encuentra en la misma Tabla (F_LFA) campo TIVLFA (0 = 19% , 1 = 8% , 2= 5% 3= 0% ) PARA EL CAMPO: tax_rate del Json

Comment: Ese es el único `tax_rate` que se ve en tu JSON, ¿cuál otro deberían tomar?

Comment: Nos muestras como tienes el JSON, pero no muestras cómo lo quieres: ¿Quieres los impuestos en cada item o después de la lista de items una lista con los impuestos de todos los ítems? ó el JSON esta correcto, el SQL nos sobra y el problema esta entre el JSON y el DataTable.

Comment: Mil Gracias por responder, Si, efectivamente el Json es el que debo lograr, ese es al que le apunto (Solo que para el ejemplo esa factura solo tiene un item, pero en la realizdad pueden y son casi siempre mas de 2 items, cada uno con su tax y retencion) Cada item tiene un tipo de impuesto, lo que requiero es que se recorra la tabla detalle de Facturas (F_LFA) y se vaya agregando a la lista ITEMS, ademas que agregue a la lista Taxes el impuesto correspondiente de cada item que se encuentra en la misma Tabla (F_LFA) campo TIVLFA (0 = 19% , 1 = 8% , 2= 5% 3= 0% ) PARA EL CAMPO: tax_rate del Json

Answer (score 0):

Respondo con la solución por si alguien lo requiere, gracias a quien lo vio y a quienes comentaron por su tiempo:

```
                    listaItems.Add(New Item(DR2("SKU"), DR2("quantity"), DR2("description"), DR2("price"), If(DR2("discount_rate") = 0, Nothing,
                                        DR2("discount_rate")), New List(Of Tax)() From {
                    New Tax() With {
                        .tax_category = "IVA",
                        .tax_rate = TASA
                    }
                }, ListaRetenciones))
```